# objective-c - NSUrlConnection makes the app crash with iOS X

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsurlconnection

I want to make a `POST` request in my app. I use the following code:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email=%@&Password=%@",self.emailTxt.text,self.pwTxt.text];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kEmailLogin]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
```

When I run this with the simulator with an iOS 9 device it works perfectly. But in my iPad with iOS X it crashes every time I perform the request.

How should I do the `POST` request to make it work in a iOS X device?

`kEmailLogin` is a variable with a `HTTPS` url for a service that returns a `JSON`.

Comment: If it crash, what's the error message? Do you know that `sendSynchronousRequest:` is deprecated? And not recommanded (blocking current thread, and if it's the main thread, block the UI)? Also, do no alloc/init the `error`.

Comment: @Larme I don't have error message. I can't debug with my iPad

Comment: You don't have an error message in console? You don't have a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" or "SIG_ABRT" or something like that?

Comment: @Larme I can't debug with my IPad, because I have to update Xcode and I can't yet. In my iPad the app crashes with no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue using `NSURLSession`.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email=%@&Password=%@",self.emailTxt.text,self.pwTxt.text];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kEmailLogin];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPBody = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

  NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;  
}];
[postDataTask resume];
```